# Mongodb searching on array / indexing

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the airbnb sample set and it has a field that looks like:

```
"amenities": ["TV", "Cable TV", "Wifi"....
```

So I'm trying to do a case-INsensitive, wildcard search (on one or more values passed in).

Only thing I've found that works is:

```
{ amenities: { $in: [ /wi/ ] }}
```

Is that the best way?

So I ran it in Compass as the dataset was imported (5600 docs), and the Explain says it took ~20ms on my machine and warned there was no index. I then created an index on the amenities column and the same search jumped up to ~100ms. I just created the index through the Compass UI, so not sure why its taking 5x as long with an index? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you use [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to check if the index is used for the selection?

Answer (score 0):

The way to run that query is:

```
{ amenities: /wi/i }

//better but not always useful
{ amenities: /wi/i }, { amenities:1, _id:0 }
```

It already traverses the array, and to be case insensitive it must be on the options.

For multikey indexes the second query won't be a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). Otherwise, it would be blazing fast.

I've tested a similar search with and without index though. Exec. time is reduced 10X. (1500ms to 150ms, in a huge collection). Measure with [Mongo Hacker.](https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker)

As you report `executionTimeMilliseconds` is not that different. But still smaller.

---

The reason why you don't see a huge decrease in time is because the index stores [each array entry separately](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index). When it finds a match, it comes back to collection to fetch the whole array field, instead of using the indexes.

Probably indexes aren't very useful for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When querying with an unanchored regex, the query executor will have to scan every index key to see if there is a match.

You might find a [collated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/index.html#collation) index to be helpful.

Create an index with the appropriate collation, like:
(strength 1 and 2 are case-insensitive)

```
 db.collection.createIndex({amenities:1},{collation:{locale:"en",strength:1}})
```

Then query using the same collation:

```
db.collection.find({amenities:"wifi"}).collation({locale:"en",strength:1})
```

The search will be case insensitive, and it can efficiently use the index.